# Mining Eth with a pathetic laptop

Tags: ether, mining, mining-pools

I am a newbie in mining, I have a couple of shitty laptops around 8-16gb ram and an Intel graphics card.
I don't pay for the electricity and don't really care if the laptop dies. I tried to search around if I can mine ETH in this laptop. but all the software wants me to set up the miner with parameters related to the AMD or Nvidea graphics card. Could anyone suggest me any miner which is easy to setup and will work for my case?

Comment: Do you have SSD in the laptops? If not, you can't get even synchronized with the network

Comment: The geth client has a software mining component that uses CPU. IMHO mining using cpu is not worth the time spent setting up the computers.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, no it doesnt have an SSD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mine, you have to get your mining node synchronized with the network. To get synchronized there are certain hardware requirements: SSD being one of them. So, since you don't have SSD, you can't get synchronized with the network. And since you can't get synchronized you can't mine either.

Even if you installed SSDs it would most likely not be worth it. I have no idea whether you can mine with Intel. If no, you'd need to mine with CPU which is totally pointless (you will never get any profit). If yes, your hashrate would still be probably very low, so it would be pointless.

Comment: Lauri's answer is 100% correct, I just wanted to add that even if you joined a mining pool (which as far as I recall would negate the need to sync the chain), your percentage of the hash rate would almost certainly be too low to ever receive any payout.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the minergate software. It won't create a lot of profit, but in your case it's worth it I guess. Here's the link: https://minergate.com/eth-mining-pool